# How to include just "parent.h" to use child class?

Tags: c++, class

I want `main.cpp` to include just `parent.h`.

main.cpp

```
#include "parent.h"

int main()
{
    Parent* base1 = new Child1();
    Parent* base2 = new Child2();
    
    base1->func();
    base2->func();

    delete base1;
    delete base2;

    return 0;
}
```

parent.h

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};
```

child1.h

```
#include "parent.h"

class Child1 : public Parent
{
public:
   void func() override;
};
```

child2.h

```
#include "parent.h"

class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
    void func() override;
};
```

I want to know how to write one header to use all classes.
I think writing many `#include "childN.h"` statements is troublesome.

Can someone give me an example of how to write `parent.h`, or some design patterns?

Comment: You cannot `new Child();` without definition of `class Child`. So, if that definition is in `child1.h`, you need to `#include "child1.h"`. However, maybe you are interested in an Abstract Factory pattern?

Comment: This makes no sense. You need to at least go into more detail what you mean by "use", and **why** you would want to do such a thing.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "use".   To create an instance of `Child1` to is necessary to `#include "child1.h"`.  Same for `Child2`.    But it is NOT necessary to include child headers in order to define a function that accepts a pointer or reference to a `Parent`, and only calls declared member functions of `Parent`  (e.g. `void call_func(Parent &o) {o.func();}` will call `Child1::func()` if an instance of `Child1` is passed to it).   Look up polymorphism for more information.   Aside:  it is also advisable that `Parent` have a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: If your goal is just to prevent writing every include file, you could just create a "global" header file where you include every single header. So `// global.h #include "parent.h" #include "child1.h" ... #include "childn.h"` and in your *.cpp you just include `global.h`

Comment: Just a note: "class Child1 : public Parent" says "a Child1 is a Parent", which makes sense in this context but is completely contrary to common language use. Use "base" and "derived" for this. ;)

Comment: **Always use include guards** in your header.

Comment: *"because I think write many #include"childn.h is troublesome"..."* **There is nothing wrong with writing it again and again. That make the intention clear of what you're going to use.** In other words, we pay for what we use.

Comment: Your class is named "`class Child1`, but you are trying to instantiate a class of a different name; "`new Chlid1();`". That could just be a typo in your question or it could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Just checking . You do know that you can put multiple classes in a single .h file? C++ is not like java where each class has to be in it's own file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally accepted good practice in C++ is to "include what you need" — that is, if your source code uses the `Child1` class, it should only include `Child1` header file. The benefits of this are better compilation time, better error messages and easier maintenance of code structure.

If you still want to have one header to use all your classes, make a file which includes all your header files:

```
// all_classes.h
#include "child1.h"
#include "child2.h"
```

Then you can do `#include "all_classes.h"` in any source file, and use all your child-classes in the same source file. Do it in addition, or better, instead of any other `#include`.

If you make another child class, you can add the corresponding `#include` to `all_classes.h`.

If you want to use all your classes whenever you use one of them, something is unusual about your use-case. Ask yourself the following questions, and then you might be able to simplify your code by deleting unnecessary stuff:

- Why do you need polymorphism? Maybe you can delete `parent` and use all the child-classes by themselves?
- Maybe you can stuff all child-classes into one header-file?
- Maybe you can make one class which implements all the functionality you need?

---

Actually, this idea is used by many big libraries — for example, you can do `#include "windows.h"` and use all of Windows's functionality. Recommended only for big libraries written by different vendors, where each library is tested and released separately.

Comment: I disagree with this.   The reason for an "all_classes.h"  is usually because a library (or class library) is implemented using multiple headers that can be selectively included, and a few too many developers resent having to work out which headers they selectively include.     Such headers - if (over)used everywhere - can increase incremental build times unnecessarily by orders of magnitude (e.g. if one of the component headers changes, virtually the entire project must be rebuilt, since all source files depend on all headers whether they use them or not).

Comment: With what exactly do you disagree?

Comment: With the recommendation to use an "all_classes.h".   Yes, some libraries/frameworks provide such headers, but that doesn't make it a good idea in general (and not necessarily even in the libraries that provide one).

Comment: A "god header" is terrible advice. It may be use by some libraries, but that doesn't mean it is not terrible. It increases compile times, it increases the risk of name clashes, it reduces the names you can use in whatever scope the header is included in. Don't use "god headers", just don't. Make headers small and self contained and only about one thing, so you can include just what you need in as narrow a scope as you need.

Comment: From the comments, it looks like I recommended usage of all-including headers, but I didn't. Does it look like I did? If yes, where? Should I edit and clarify this answer? Maybe someone who sees a problem add another answer?

Comment: @anatolyg "From the comments, it looks like I recommended usage of all-including headers, but I didn't" - eehhh, you kind of did when you said "Make a file which includes all your header files".

Comment: I've clarified my answer; I hope it doesn't look like that now.